# Pushing ID's in array through function

Tags: javascript, easyrtc

I'm writing a chat app and a function in it checks if a user is logged in or not. When a user logs in, it writes the ID to an array. I have a use a function that can check if a user is logged in to the server, but as an argument you need to give it a user ID, which are contained in the array.

Here's where I'm stuck - If the functions checks to see if the ID is logged in and it determines its not, it returns a value of "false". I'd like to run all of these through the function one after another. How do I then remove that name from the array?

```
var loggedInUsers = [];
var user = easyrtc.idToName(i); //converts random digits to assigned ID
loggedInUsers.push(user);
easyrtc.getConnectStatus(???)  //Checks if a user is logged in
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Use `loggedInUsers.splice(index, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

use .indexOf method:

```
loggedInUsers.indexOf(userID) > -1 // user id is in the array
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove that user from the `loggedInUsers` array, Try removing it with `splice`.

`loggedInUsers.splice(i, 1);`

Here `i` is `index` of `user ID` [chech here for splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?v=example)

Comment: Now how would I run the array through the function getConnectionStatus to check if the user is logged in?